# Warning: Prop `src` did not match

Tags: warnings, prop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgGVt.png)

trong nextjs push query param vào url khi reload lại thì tôi đang gặp vấn đề next-dev.js:20 Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server: "/images/footer/gift-active.png" Client: "/images/footer/gift.png"